# Social login - Laravel 4.2 application - need additional data

Tags: laravel, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-4.2

I'm using this package, https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel but only getting id and user name.
I need additional data like email, firstname, lastname etc

I used this package as also need to integrate login with google also

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-42-and-socialite Socailite is compatible with laravel 5 + version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 'Facebook' => array(
       'client_id'     => 'aaa----aaaaa',
       'client_secret' => 'xxx----xxxxx',
       'callback_url'  => 'http://staging.crossinghoods.com/customer-account/login/fb/callback',
       'scope'         => array('email'),
   ),
2. `$result = json_decode( $fb->request( '/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,picture' ), true );`

These two steps solved my issue. But it was not found in the documentation.

Comment: that one is Facebook [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/),you will need an api key on some cases. you can try using the [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to familiarise yourself.